# Email date parser when right click on browser

Tags: c#, javascript

[EDIT] I rewrote the question to mention specifically the context menu. Thanks for the remark.

I'm looking to create a date parser for email, so that in case of text selection and right click, there will be an option in the context menu to identify the selected text (say `7/6/2011 10:30 meeting with John`) and add to my calendar (I'm using Google's calendar).

I was thinking of developing such a thing in Javascript, is there a way to hook up to the right-click context menu of the browser without the use of extensions? 
Or it's better to create desktop application that hooks up to the "copy" event?
Is there a library for date parsing on Javascript or others?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you're probably aware, all browsers use the right mouse button to pop up a context menu.

Most browsers allow you to disable this feature via Javascript, but a few do not -- notably Opera. In older versions of Opera it was simply not possible to use right click in Javascript. In newer versions it is possible, but the feature still had to be switched on by the user in their browser configuration. Only in very recent versions has this feature defaulted to being switched on.

Therefore, if any of your users are running Opera, you will likely have problems with any functionality you imlement for the right-click.

There's quite a detailed write up of this issue here: http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html

To answer the final part of your question: You asked if there's a decent date parser library for Javascript. Obviously you know about JS's built-in Date object, but that can only get you so far. For more advanced parsing, I recommend checking out this library: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: I didn't notice not mentioning it should be a command on context menu. Thanks. I've checked the datejs.com link, but I'm not sure it will identify and parse soemthing like "3.3.2011 10:00 meeting" because it contains other things rather than the date. Maybe regular expressions library will be more suitable.

Comment: @shahar - datejs can work with both dates and times, and combinations of the two. However, regardless of the date library you use, please be aware that a date like "2.6.2011" is ambiguous, and you can never be sure of getting the right answer unless you specify whether it's d.m.y or m.d.y. Both are in common use.